# How can I make phone calls on the internet IPhone 6

Tags: iphone, internet, wifi-calling

I have a remote location were I have only satellite service, no cell service.

When I first purchased my iPhone 6 to my surprise I received messages (voice) left on phone at this location. I couldn't call people back but could text them over the internet.

Now after returning to the remote location I can not get any more messages left on my phone from voicemail. I am still getting text messages, which I also did with my iPhone 4S.

Did an update wipe out this ability or have I turned something off by mistake? I have all of my data turned on to WiFi.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to enable Wifi Calling on your device. Turn on Wi-Fi calling in `Settings > Phone > Wi-Fi Calling`. For more, check out the [Apple page on Wifi Calling](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203032).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cross-platform solution (in case you don't want to become more tied down to iOS), there are numerous VOIP solutions. With Skype, for example, you can purchase a phone number for a pretty reasonable price. (Or just use Skype-to-Skype for free.) I know you didn't ask for a cross-platform solution, but you didn't rule it out either - and either way, this could solve your problem.